# How to Set BackgroundColor on ImageView on Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I tried a couple things and nothing is working... I'm trying to change the BackgroundColor on a ImageView on Android, but nothing happens...

Here is my xml:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="350dp"
   android:layout_height="550dp"
   android:layout_above="@+id/btnInfo"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fundo"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnInfo"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fundo"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:contentDescription="@string/backgroundMain" />
```

And the code:

```
public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("Teste", "In the onStart() event 5");

        ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe if I set a different color, instead of white, I could see it... ¬¬ Well, my code is working... Thanks for who read that ;)

Comment: I was gonna point that out, but I thought nah couldn't be!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

RGB:255, 255, 255 is the color code for WHITE. Since your parent layout background color is also white you won't see the difference.

Try changing color like

```
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

Or else change the background color of parent layout.

Comment: Yeah, what a shame... When I realize that was the white color the problem, was too late... Thanks! ;-)

Comment: is it possible to set up both on xml file ? Changing background color with background image ?

Comment: @Abhishek V I have an image view where i use both black and white shades of 'library_add_check' icon of https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=check&icon=library_add_check&style=baseline  to represent 'select all' and 'uncheck all' feature,I need the parent toolbar color(ie,different in each activity screen) for the black icon shade to represent 'uncheck all' and the white shade for 'select all', so how can i change the black icon background on change??

Answer (score 27):

There's nothing wrong with your code. But I would prefer doing this through xml , This will also solve your problem. Just add this in your ImageView tag.

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 22):

In theory it should work...but try like this:

```
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a XML file placed in drawable folder, you might need to use:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drawable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `PorterDuff.Mode`:

```
imageView1.setColorFilter(colorCode,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

`PorterDuff.mode` gives a way of composing and overlaying images in Android, see also [What does PorterDuff.Mode mean in android graphics.What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280027/what-does-porterduff-mode-mean-in-android-graphics-what-does-it-do)