# Change thumb color from a seekbar

Tags: android, slider, seekbar

I have a seekbar and i am trying to change the thumb color. I found two photos that describes what i actually want to do.
I have this seekbar (default) :
[image]

and i am trying to change it's color thumb like **this.. :**
(I know how to change background progress color but not the thumb color)..

```
seekBar1calling.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this using java code? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just used an online style generator which gave me what i needed

http://android-holo-colors.com/

Just choose the widget and color you want and you are ready! ;)

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
mySeekbar.getThumb().setColorFilter(myColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Edit: method getThumb is only available since API 16+ (Jelly Bean).

Comment: do you know how to do this in xml?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are old and didn't work for me, this did.

```
seekbar.setThumbTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.disabled));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and easy solution which worked for me as expected. Just implement this code after you initialized the seekbar to avoid NPE's.

You have to define the color itself under **res/values/colors.xml**

```
int blue = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.seekbar_blue);
filterSeekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(blue, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
filterSeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(blue, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

That's all!

**Note:** The color of the Progress-Background is not as dark as the Button / Thumb itself.
If you want to know more about the PorfuerDuff part check this answer on Stackoverflow:
[Phasmal & Lee's answer to PorfuerDuff modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280027/what-does-porterduff-mode-mean-in-android-graphics-what-does-it-do)