# Android View OnDraw method: fill everything EXCEPT some view

Tags: java, android, ondraw

In theory, let's say I have a View that lookes like this:

[image]

it's made in 'onDraw' by methods like 'drawCircle', 'drawRect', etc...

...And now let's say I have an imaginable Circle(well, a Circle object that I don't paint on the View) and I want the view to be filled with some color EXCEPT inside the imaginable Circle... so I want it to look like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this???

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how to do it, but look in to PorterDuff. [Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280027/what-does-porterduff-mode-mean-in-android-graphics-what-does-it-do)

Here is an example I found at [ProgramCreek](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.PorterDuff) (exapmle #8):

```
private Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
  Bitmap output=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas=new Canvas(output);
  final Paint paint=new Paint();
  final Rect rect=new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
  final RectF rectF=new RectF(rect);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  canvas.drawARGB(0,0,0,0);
  paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
  canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF,roundPixels,roundPixels,paint);
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,rect,rect,paint);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't view the link, are you sure the hypertxt really reffers to something?

Comment: Hope it helps! Cheers