# In Android, is it possible to display images one over the other?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I'm using Android Studio to make an app where you can create your own animal, and I want to know how I can layer pictures on clicking a button, if it can be done.
For example, suppose I want to create a teddy bear- I will first click a button to display the bear's plain body, then clicking another button should layer a transparent image of the eyes over the same body (and so on for the nose, mouth, clothes, etc.) I have attached two images as examples of which pictures should appear one over the other when their respective buttons are clicked.

IMAGE 1: This is the body of the bear that will appear when I click the button that says "body"

IMAGE 2: A transparent image of the eyes, dimensions same as the previous image. On clicking the button "eyes" this image should be overlayed onto the previous one

[image: This is the body of the bear that will appear when I click a button that says "body"]
[image: A transparent image of the eyes, dimensions same as the previous pic. On clicking the button "eyes" this image should be overlayed onto the previous one]

Comment: use Framelayout......it is specifically designed for that

Comment: Are you aware of Alpha Compositing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing - and more specifically Porter-Duff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280027/what-does-porterduff-mode-mean-in-android-graphics-what-does-it-do

Comment: You can use a RelativeLayout for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it, but I assume you know about `OpenGL`. That is the standard graphics renderer. With it you can layer as many images as you want.

For instance, you can load the images into the `sampler` and click-by-click you render the collection of images (given the positioning is taken care of).