# Android Xamarin: FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag is null

Tags: android, xamarin.android, fragmentmanager

I am trying to understand the FragmentMananger better.

I "inflate" my fragment in a FrameLayout, what works fine.

```
var fragmentTag = typeof(MyFragment).Name;
myFragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
               .Add(Resource.Id.FrameLayout, myFragment, fragmentTag)
               .Commit();
```

But now the question is, at what moment can i find my fragment via the TagSearch.
Because after the BeginTransaction()

```
FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<MyFragment>(typeof(MyFragment).Name
```

is still null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [executePendingTransactions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()) method after `Commit` method, it will execute immediately.

And you can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170693/8632294) case.

Here is the [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/MergeBitmap) based on your last [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130773/xamarin-andoid-merge-imageview-with-canvasview). I have add some codes in the project:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
Fragment1 fragment = (Fragment1)FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
if (fragment == null)
{
    fragment = new Fragment1();
    fragmentTransaction.Add(fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).Commit();
    FragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
}

Fragment1 f=FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<Fragment1>(typeof(Fragment1).Name);
if (f != null)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Fragment1 is not null", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Fragment1 is  null", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, `.ExecutePendingTransactions()` makes the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try change tag something static. Like this.

```
myFragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
               .Add(Resource.Id.FrameLayout, myFragment, "MyFragmentTag")
               .Commit();

FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<MyFragment>("MyFragmentTag");
```

Comment: This does not make any difference